# How to disable workflow's print when compiling latex from python?

Tags: python, latex

Good morning!

I'm compiling latex documents from python in Ubuntu 16.04, but I want to disable the printing that appears in my shell when doing it (same printing that appears when compiling using a TeX editor like TexWorks).

The code I'm using is the following:

```
def compila_latex(nombre):

    cmd  = ['pdflatex','-interaction','nonstopmode', nombre + '.tex']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    proc.communicate()

    retcode = proc.returncode
    if not retcode == 0:
        os.unlink(nombre + '.pdf')
        raise ValueError('Hay un error con la compilación del documento.')

    cmd  = ['pdflatex','-interaction','nonstopmode', nombre + '.tex']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    proc.communicate()

    retcode = proc.returncode
    if not retcode == 0:
        os.unlink(nombre + '.pdf')
        raise ValueError('Error')

    list_files     = os.listdir(os.curdir)
    list_aux_files = [fil[len(nombre):] for fil in list_files if fil[:len(nombre)] == nombre]

    for end in list_aux_files:

        if end != '.tex' and end != '.pdf':
            os.unlink(nombre + end)
```

Note: I'm compiling twice due to index and page numering.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `pdflatex <options> file.tex > capture.txt` and then you can delete `capture.txt`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your point... Should I write the following?  cmd  = ['pdflatex','-interaction','nonstopmode', nombre + '.tex', '>', 'capture.txt']

Comment: Try it; `> file.ext` writes any standard output to `file.ext`, thereby removing any of the printing. See [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981) even though you would not use the stored output.